# Executing sp_addlinkedserver within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[sc_Server_Link]
    @ServerName varchar(255),
    @ServerSource varchar(255),
    @DatabaseName varchar(255),
    @UserName varchar(255),
    @UserPass varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM sys.sysservers WHERE srvname = @ServerName )
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
                @server = @ServerName,
                @srvproduct = '',
                @provider = 'sqlncli',
                @datasrc = @ServerSource,
                @location = '',
                @provstr = '',
                @catalog = @DatabaseName

        --Add credentials and options to this linked server
        IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM sys.linked_logins WHERE remote_name = @UserName)
            EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
                @rmtsrvname = @ServerName,
                @useself = 'false',
                @rmtuser = @UserName,
                @rmtpassword = @UserPass

        --Set Options
        EXEC sp_serveroption @ServerName, 'rpc out', true;
    END
END
```

Executing the procedure works fine but afterwards, every time I try to do a transaction... the transaction works but I get the following errors:

> Msg 15002, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addlinkedserver, Line 71
> The procedure 'sys.sp_addlinkedserver' cannot be executed within a transaction.
>
> Msg 15002, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addlinkedsrvlogin, Line 35
> The procedure 'sys.sp_addlinkedserver' cannot be executed within a transaction.
>
> Msg 15002, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_serveroption, Line 37
> The procedure 'sys.sp_addlinkedserver' cannot be executed within a transaction.

- How can I stop these errors?
- How can I correct my stored procedure so this won't happen again?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23734809/3393505

Comment: Doesn't the error message tell you all you need to know already???

Comment: Even if I stop using this sp... I'm still stuck with those 3 errors every insert/update/delete I do in my local database

Comment: Close the transaction if you still have your session open. Otherwise close your session. Just a guess.

Comment: If that doesn't help (or you can't figure out how to), restart the SQL Server database engine (how to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403394.aspx))