# How to grant user sys.admin role in SQL via Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Just to clear the wind I am aware off that granting users sysadmin in T-SQL in not a good thing but per customer requirements it needs to be done.

I have this :

```
public void AddUserToServer(List<string> users, List<string> servers)
{
        foreach (var server in servers)
        {
            setConnection(server);

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                string sql =
                    "USE [master]" +
                    " CREATE LOGIN" + " [TP1\\" + user + "] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], " +
                    "DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english] " +
                    "EXEC sys.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'TP1\\" + user + "', @rolename = N'sysadmin'";

                _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
            }
        }
}
```

I got the above script by creating the user manually in ssms and then generated the script. However when running it I am getting this current error:

> 'The procedure 'sys.sp_addsrvrolemember' cannot be executed within a transaction.

So I changed it to :

```
            string sql =
                "USE [master]" +
                " CREATE LOGIN" + " [TP1\\" + user + "] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], " +
                "DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english] " +
                "GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS TO[TP1\\" + user + "]";
```

This creates the user **BUT** I do not get the sysadmin role.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So typical that I spent some time on this and finally after positing I find the answer.

I believe that this is a question more people will ask so I can provide what I found:

```
    string sql =
    "USE [master]" +
    " CREATE LOGIN" + " [TP1\\" + user + "] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], " +
    "DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english] " +
     "EXEC sys.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'TP1\\" + user + "', @rolename = N'sysadmin'";


    _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, sql);
```

NOTE:

```
TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction
```

> Starting with EF6 Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() by default will wrap
>   the command in a transaction if one was not already present. There are
>   overloads of this method that allow you to override this behavior if
>   you wish. Also in EF6 execution of stored procedures included in the
>   model through APIs such as ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction() does the
>   same (except that the default behavior cannot at the moment be
>   overridden).

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932496/stored-procedure-working-when-calling-exec-sp-and-throws-with-ef6-on-sql-azure)